# "There are many examples of Xs and Ys in our society." When we want to generalize a particular kind of person to a large number of people

Tags: sentence-structure

In Persian, Somali(an Afroasiatic language) and Arabic when we want to generalize a particular kind of person (as a symbol)  to a large number of people we say:

> We have many Xs & Ys & etc in our society, these children are our future.

Or

> There are many Xs & Ys & etc(somone's name+[s]) in our society, these children are our future.

I wonder if we can say the following sentences in English:

> "There are many examples of Xs and Ys in our society."

Or

> There are many Xs & Ys among ourselves who can build our future.

Are these structures acceptable?

NOTE: X & Y are fictitous names. (e.g. Xs: Toms & Ys: Juliets)

Comment: Your question is not perfectly clear. Are you asking about fictitious common names in English (e.g. *Any Tom, Dick, or Harry would know the answer to this question* or *The average Joe doesn't want to travel two hours to work*)  or about using a particular named person as an exemplar, in the plural?  *There are few Elon Musks in our society.*?

Comment: Note: For standard American English, you overuse the ampersand. Unless you're space constrained (like on a logo or sign or tweet), you should write out "and" rather than "&" in lists. "Persian, Somali, _and_ Arabic", not "Persian, Somali, & Arabic".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo In spite of the fact that you are right, I'm truly surprised by MaciejStachowski's answer. I mean *How could he answer?*

Comment: Maciej begins "If I understand you correctly..."    I assume that the "Tom" in that answer is a common name chosen for the purposes of illustration, not an actual name.  A name so common that it cannot be linked to any one person since it can be linked to millions or at least hundreds of thousands.  *Let's call him 'Tom'... There are many Toms out there who ...* But we also employ this rhetorical trope with actual names.  *We need more Jonas Salks and Albert Sabins*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You know, I was just thinking about my last comment, and finally I came to this conclusion that  ‘That’s absolute nonsense, Amirhosein!’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the context is something like:

> Tom is 40 years old and living with his mother. (...more about Tom). But there are many Toms in our society - 42% of people aged 30-50 have never moved out to their own place.

I think it's an understandable metaphor, although I'm having a hard time finding a citation for it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but what are we gonna say if we want to mention another person (who has the same situation as Tom) simultaneously. I mean, I wonder if this sentence sounds natural: "But there are many Toms **& Jacks** in our society - 42% of people aged 30-50 have never moved out to their own place."

Comment: @AmirhoseinRiazi I don't think there's much of a difference - if you've introduced two people in the same situation, then "Toms and Jacks" (I'd avoid using an ampersand when unnecessary) sounds fine.

Comment: +1. *... and there are many Amirhoseins on ELL asking questions about what is idiomatic in English*.   **Amirhosein** would have to have been mentioned previously in the context, as Maciej does in the answer.

Comment: The ampersand suggests that Tom and Jack are a known duo, like *Simon & Garfunkel*. There's no problem with having multiple names *...many Toms and Jacks and Janes ...*

Comment: *Therefore, I'm so lucky that there are many @Tᴚoɯɐuo s and Maciejs here in this site*.